# why does my github pages doesn't look exactly the same with the one on my local machine?

Tags: html, css, git, twitter-bootstrap, github

The font size of my work on github pages tend to appear bigger than the ones in my local machine, i've tried to solve this issue without any meaningful progress.

I tried reducing the font size from my local machine before pushing it to gitub and it still fails
check the pictures[image][image]

Comment: Try inspecting the page and see if the github version has any additional styles applied.
Also, depending on how you are publishing the code, you may need to refresh your cache to load the page in its latest state.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the page is zoomed by your browser? Either github or localhost. Because generally the browser keep the zoom for a given web domain...

Comment: Probably you set your browser to zoom out for github or zoom in on your local development environment.so check once that it is not zoom in or zoom out and also check by using inspect element that which font size are being applied when deployed.